# Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder could not be converted to string in laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel

I have been trying to debug a problem for the past two days, my code, as follows, is first attempting to retrieve the category by it's id:

```
$term = category::get(['id']);
```

Then using this retrieved term for querying models with a foreign key on that category:

```
$categories = HelpCenter::whereHas('category', function($category) use ($term)
{
    $category->where('category_id','=',$category);
})
  ->take(5)->get();
```

Unfortunately my code throws the error `Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder could not be converted to string`

Comment: what are you doing with that single item array in the get function?

Comment: This is only part of your code, you are trying to dump/debug the Query Builder (probably using `echo`); that is what the message is saying. Please provide the complete code that is throwing the backtrace.

Comment: To get id of category from database

Comment: Change `$term=category::get(['id']);` to `$term=category::all()->pluck('id')` to have all id in array.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This line of code does not make sense:

```
$category->where('category_id','=',$category);
```

`$category` is an Eloquent Builder instance so what you are effectively doing is this:

```
EloquentBuilder->where('category_id', '=', EloquentBuilder);
```

I'm assuming the second `$category` variable was meant to be `$term` like this:

```
$category->where('category_id','=',$term);
```

But that will still cause some issues, which I'll explain in a bit. First though, I think you should rename the variable so it makes a bit more intuitive sense. Instead of `$category`, name it `$query` so things don't get mixed up.

```
$categories = HelpCenter::whereHas('category', function($query) use ($term)
{
    $query->where('category_id', '=', $term);
})
->take(5)->get();
```

Next, we need to tackle a few more things.

1. In your example, the `$term` variable is never used. I am assuming that it should be an array of category ids.
2. I'm also assuming that `$term` is what you want to pass into the `where` method.

To tackle #1, you are currently getting a collection of category instances. You're actually getting every single category in your database. I'm not sure if that's your intention, but either way, you probably still want an array of category ids. As @smartrahat suggested, use the `pluck` method.

```
$term = category::get(['id'])->pluck('id');
```

To tackle #2, you want to find all categories that match the ids you are passing. You can use the `whereIn` method for that.

```
$query->whereIn('category_id', $term);
```

All together, it should look something like this:

```
$term=category::get(['id'])->pluck('id');

$categories = HelpCenter::whereHas('category', function($query) use ($term)
{
    $query->whereIn('category_id', $term);
})
->take(5)->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use both `take()` and `get()`.  Just just one or the other.

Comment: Agree. I got the same error because I wrote my query and did not call `->get()` at the end

Answer (score 0):

```
$product = $data->with('productimages')->with('categories')->where('id', $id)->first();
```